# Save in plist to a program directory

Tags: objective-c, plist

i need to save a .plist file NOT to documents, but to the core of program.
For example my program called "123" and if i save data, then send my app to my friend and he opens this app he could see saved data, no matter where he puts this program. I can't find solution to this problem, please help me.

I'm making mac app.
and i save plist with

```
 [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:FBCover1.text= 
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Cover1.attributedStringValue]
 toFile:@"/Users/admin/FBCover1.plist"];
```

Comment: Use the Application Support folder sub folder for your app. (Create it if it does not exist)

Comment: "Application Support" doesn't (easily) transfer between computers, @uchuugaka

Comment: No easier nor difficult than the app bundle. What is your point? If you need to update data, update data in the proper places provided. If you need to update an app, do that properly. Code Sign. If you are not doing this you hate your users and customers because you don't care at all about security and you want to be an attack vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preamble: this is an awful idea. What you should do is create a document-based application and pass your document backwards and forwards.

Literal answer:

You can use `NSBundle` to get the path of the resources folder within your application bundle with something like:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
```

The resources folder is where application resources, such as plists, are meant to go. You're supposed to consider your application bundle as read-only in general but that's as good a choice as any if you want to hack away.

Answer (score 2):

***General answer:***

If you're trying to do this on iPhone (you didn't tag this for iOS or MacOS), this isn't going to work as this will break your code signing.

If you're doing this on MacOS and you're using code signing, you'll have the same problem.

There may be places where you could save and share data, such as Game Center or DropBox or Box or some other cloud storage mechanism, but you'll need to pick up and make use of some additional API's or frameworks.

***Specific answer just for you:***

Instead of:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:FBCover1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Cover1.attributedStringValue] toFile:@"/Users/admin/FBCover1.plist"];
```

which is big and ugly and I don't know what the heck it's doing, why not save your string this way?

```
NSString * stringToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Cover1.attributedStringValue];
if(stringToSave)
{
    NSError * error = nil;
    BOOL success = [stringToSave writeToFile: @"/Users/admin/FBCovert1.txt" atomically: YES encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: @error];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog( @"error in saving - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

This saves the raw string into a file.

If you want to do it as a plist, then create a NSDictionary and save your string as the value with some appropriate key.

Comment: add info to the question.

Comment: That "`.plist`" file is going into the home folder of a user named "`admin`", which is *not* the core of the program. Does your friend have an account named "`admin`" also? Is your MacOS going to be code signed?

Comment: Not it's not going to be signed.

Comment: In my case, now i use this path in order to test, but that's the point, i want to change it.